# Find the 4-digit number

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Some said that [my last puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15664/identify-the-missing-symbols) was difficult, and the same thing for [the one before it](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15658/create-a-word-search), so here is an easier one, to celebrate Friday I guess (although it's almost Saturday in some places).

Here are directions to obtain the 4-digit number:

> 96321112666574122223698741578963214123698754442226632147

**What is the 4-digit number?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> 2685

Explanation:

> The numbers represent the directions of the numpad. The "5" in the sequence are used to separate the four numbers of the puzzle. 
>  [image]
>  The red dots represent the starting point for each number.

What is this number?

> It's supposed to be the number of this question in Puzzling! Note that this might not be accurate, because the site stats don't always refresh immediately. At this moment, I see that the question counter displays "2684", probably it's what JLee saw too before writing his question.

Comment: @JLee Fixed the second number, i'm still creating the picture